# Discord.py access all members in all servers of bot without a command?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to retrieve all members in all servers of the bot without a command or event call? Currently, it works using a command, but I want to make it an async function that I call on the bot's startup. I've tried passing "client" into the function and that didn't work either.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="%", intents = intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is up and running")
  await check()
  await currency_update()

@client.command()
async def currency_update(ctx):
  for guild in client.guilds:
     for member in guild.members:
        print(member)
  await asyncio.sleep(3600)
  await currency_update(ctx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make `currency_update` a command, make it a simple async function without any arguments

```py
async def currency_update():
  for guild in client.guilds:
     for member in guild.members:
        print(member)
  await asyncio.sleep(3600)
  await currency_update(ctx)
```

I'd suggest the use of a while loop instead of recursion.

---

If you want to start the async functions "in the background" use `asyncio.create_task`

```py
import asyncio

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is up and running")
  asyncio.create_task(check())
  asyncio.create_task(currency_update())
```

Comment: I've already tried this (without ctx) and it didn't work. It works only when it's a command and I don't really understand why.

Comment: Can you try putting some debugging print statements?

Comment: Actually I may have found the issue but don't know how to solve it. Apparently in the on_ready function only the first 2 lines get run and then it stops. I edited the post to show the lines I'm talking about. Is it because I can't have 2 async functions in a row?

Comment: You can have, but when `await`ing an async function you're waiting for it to finish, if you want them to run "in the background" use `asyncio.create_task`. Let me edit my answer

Comment: Also whats the benefit of while loop over recursion?

Comment: You cannot really compare recursion with a while loop, they're totally different. Take a look at: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182314/recursion-or-while-loops